# removing text except digits and Nan from Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have **Dataframe** that contains **five columns** (i.e., source, battery,Temperature, time, and distance) as showing in the attached pic

[image]

I would like to remove the text from the each column and keep the digits only 
secondly, i need to remove the Nan that appears in rows

**For example, the expected output would look like this**

[image]

**this is the code that I have written so far**

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import re
URL = 'https://wastemanagement.post-iot.lu/measurement/measurements?source=83512& pageSize=1000000000&dateFrom=2019-10-26&dateTo=2019-10-28'
req = requests.get(URL,auth=('xxx', 'xxx') )
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["measurements"])
cols_to_keep =['source','battery','c8y_TemperatureMeasurement','time','c8y_DistanceMeasurement']
df_final = df[cols_to_keep]
df_final = df_final.rename(columns={'c8y_TemperatureMeasurement': 'Temperature Or T','c8y_DistanceMeasurement':'Distance'})
for col in df_final:
 df_final[col] = [''.join(re.findall("\d*\.?\d+", item)) for item in df_final[col]]
```

Comment: do you want to remove the rows completely that have NaN in any column or just replace NaN with nothing?

Comment: @Arsal thanks for the help. replace the NaN with the value of the previous or next row. For example if there is a value 23 in the next or previous row , replace NaN with 23. Secondly, I want to remove the text from the each column and keep the digits only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer for removing the text is

```
enter code here
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://nnn.com/measurement/measurements?source=83512&pageSize=1000000000&dateFrom=2019-10-26&dateTo=2019-10-28'
req = requests.get(URL,auth=('xxxx', 'xxxx') )
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)
df= json_normalize(json_dict['measurements'])
df = df_final.rename(columns={'source.id': 'source', 'battery.percent.value': 'battery', 'c8y_TemperatureMeasurement.T.value': 'Temperature Or T','c8y_DistanceMeasurement.distance.value':'Distance'})
 cols_to_keep =['source' ,'battery', 'Temperature Or T', 'time', 'Distance']
 df_final = df[cols_to_keep]
```